# authenticated bypass firewall

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-firewall

We currently use Windows Firewall to restrict RDS access to a hosted server by IP address on port 3389.  We use Server 2008 Enterprise and it's really our only option since it's hosted by a 3rd party.

We need to allow authenticated bypass rules for non-domain computers and domain users, but I don't know how to set it up or if it's even feasible.

If it is, my question is what is Microsoft's recommended method of securing a non-domain computer / domain user authenticated bypass rule over the internet?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753463%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but that article doesn't clarify what I'm asking.  I've already referenced this article and because it doesn't address my problem completely I've decided to see if I can find some answers from people who might have a bit more experience with IPSec and Certificates.